# Restart VPN using cron-job service

Tags: networking, 18.04, vpn, cron, 19.04

Is there any way to automate restarting/resetting my VPN service after my killswitch kicks on? I imagine that a cronjob will need to be setup for every minute to check to see if I have an active connection if not a .sh file needs to run that stops the service and restarts it. When you perform pings is there any way to capture that data? I have performed pings with the killswitch on before and it won't return anything to me. Does anyone have any ideas or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Thanks

Comment: cron is the wrong thing to use here. create a service if the vpn does not already provide one. systemd has options to restart a service when it crashes/is killed.

Comment: @Rinzwind the provider is Mullvad but they leverage Wireguard as the application to use. There is no front end user interface as far I can tell (during the initial setup). I followed the instructions to set it up as a service via their website guide but I just had a disconnect today and I can tell its still blocking any web traffic. This is the reason why I mentioned using Cron to check that it is still working okay. I think the service never got shut off but because the process never stopped running it just isn't running how I intended it to run.